# Как правильно сравнить данные 2-х массивов объектов?

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 массива:

```
const arr1 = [
    {line:"1", id: "2"}, 
    {line:"2", id: "4"}, 
    {line:"4", id: "5"}
]
const arr2 = [
    {example:"112", idExample: "2"},
    {example:"233", idExample: "2"}, 
    {example:"444", idExample: "10"}
]
```

Как сравнить эти 2 массива и в случае если значения id и idExample равны, то что-то вывести.

Comment: уточните вопрос; сравнивать можно по разному: каждый элемент с каждым, или элементы с одинаковой позицией

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const arr1 = [
    {line:"1", id: "2"}, 
    {line:"2", id: "4"}, 
    {line:"4", id: "5"}
]
const arr2 = [
    {example:"112", idExample: "1"},
    {example:"233", idExample: "2"}, 
    {example:"444", idExample: "10"}
]

arr1.forEach(itemId=>{
  arr2.forEach(itemIdExample=>{
    itemId.id === itemIdExample.idExample ? console.log("верно") : '' 
  })
})
```

Выведет один раз "верно" так как совпадает только одно значение idExample: 2 и id: 2

Comment: Да, спасибо! Почти так же уже сам реализовал)

Answer (score -1):

```js
function checkArray(arr1,arr2,key1,key2){
  if(arr1.length != arr2.length) return false;
  let arrSize = arr1.length;
  for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++){
    if(arr1[i][key1]!=arr2[i][key2])return false;
  }
  return true;
}

const arr1 = [
    {line:"1", id: "2"}, 
    {line:"2", id: "4"}, 
    {line:"4", id: "5"}
]
const arr2 = [
    {example:"112", idExample: "2"},
    {example:"233", idExample: "4"}, 
    {example:"444", idExample: "5"}
]
console.log(checkArray(arr1, arr2, 'id', 'idExample'))

const arr3 = [
    {line:"1", id: "2"}, 
    {line:"2", id: "4"}, 
    {line:"4", id: "5"}
]
const arr4 = [
    {example:"112", idExample: "2"},
    {example:"233", idExample: "8"}, 
    {example:"444", idExample: "5"}
]
console.log(checkArray(arr3, arr4, 'id', 'idExample'))
```